# No sound - but Ubuntu thinks there should be

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I can't get any sound out of my laptop.

Ubuntu displays sound options, function keys work to adjust volume and pavucontrol shows "Built-in Analogue Stereo" output to "Speakers".

Nothing what-so-ever makes any sound.

I have tried:
-Re-install Ubuntu 17.04
-Newer kernels
-Change to OSS4
-Even installed Windows to check if it was a hardware error (worked fine and driver displayed as Realtek Audio)

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am very stumped and help would be appreciated!

Thanks in adv.

Info below:

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)



    aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

Call up `alsamixer` and unmute the speakers would be my guess.  That kind of hardware flag seems like it is not always exported/visible to Pulseaudio.